# Get comments of public facebook post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to download every comment on [a public facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/beth.mansfield.9/posts/10207885721596563) (it's one of those "can you do this basic algebra problem" posts - I want to see what percent of the comments get it right).

The [Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/comments) shows that I should be able to just `GET graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{object-id}/comments`.

I believe the `object-id` of this post is `{user-id}_{post-id}`, where `post-id` is the id in the url. So given this url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/beth.mansfield.9/posts/10207885721596563
```

The `user-id` of `facebook.com/beth.mansfield.9` is `1101752663` (from [findmyfbid.com](http://findmyfbid.com/)), and the `post-id` is `10207885721596563` (from the url), which makes the `object-id="1101752663_10207885721596563"`.

When I try [`graph.facebook.com/v2.5/1101752663_10207885721596563/comments` in the Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=1101752663_10207885721596563%2Fcomments&version=v2.5), though, I get:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to get the comments? There are close to a million so loading them all in the browser and scraping with javascript would be unfeasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a user profile. You can only get data of a user profile if that specific user authorized your App. In that case, you would need to authorize with the `user_posts` permission. Just because it is public, does not mean you can get the data - that would only work for Pages.

Comment: Ahh, well that's crummy. I just tried it with [a public post from a page](https://www.facebook.com/nytimes/posts/10150628170209999) in the [Grap API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=5281959998_10150628170209999%2Fcomments&version=v2.5) and got actual data. I'll have to find another way to do it. Thanks!